# Timeout for Volume Shadow Copy (programmatically)

Tags: delphi-xe2

When I start the Volume Shadow copy programmatically how much time is maximum that I should wait before the Shadow is prepared ie: before I proceed taking backup. Just now it happens with about 10 secs in my machine. But I need timeout when deploying elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article (which describes the flow of events that happen when you create a Shadow Copy using a "Hardware Provider") has a nice sequence diagram that illustrates the timeout in the 'I/O Flush & Hold' window: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384615(v=vs.85).aspx

The total timeout *enforced by VSS* in this window is **60 seconds**. Hence, you can expect the IVssAsync::Wait() call, on the IVssAsync pointer returned by the call to DoSnapshotSet(), to automatically timeout in 60 seconds.

As such, you do not need to implement a timeout yourself, since VSS does this for you.